# Win10: Finding specific root certificate in certificate store?

Tags: windows-10, certificate

I know how to remove certificates. But I face the issue that I don't know which certificate it is. I still have the `.pfx` file. So how do I find out which certificate in the store corresponds to this `.pfx` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [display the issuer and other information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588740/how-do-i-view-pfx-file-information-in-a-visual-manner) of each certificate with this CMD:

```
certutil -dump "<path\filename.pfx>"
```

Quotes are needed only if there are spaces in filename or path.

Then compare that info with that shown in the certificate manager (in *Microsoft Management Console*, MMC).